# How and why do we prove that $\mathcal{l}(I) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{l}(J_i)$ where $I=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty J_i$ is an open interval?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Leading up to a treatment on Lebesgue outer measure, I have been shown a proof that

> $\mathcal{l}(I) \leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{l}(J_i)$ for $I=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty J_i$ is an open interval (where $\mathcal{l}$ is the length function, i.e. $\mathcal{l}(I)=b-a$ if $I=(a,b)$).

The proof creates slightly larger intervals for each $J_i=(a_i,b_i)$ by adding an amount $\epsilon>0$ to each endpoint and considers a finite open cover of the closed interval $[a,b]$ by these enlarged $J_i$'s.

My question is, what is the purpose of this discussion, what does it show us, and what is the intuition behind the proof/why does this need to be proved at all?

Comment: The property is evident using *another* property(es) of the Lebesgue measure... that you haven't proved yet.

Comment: If you are interested in some particular proof of this fact, you could perhaps mention the source of the proof, too. BTW a proof of this is also given in Oxtoby's Measure and Category as Theorem 1.5.

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether this still qualifies as fair use, but here is [page 3](http://i.stack.imgur.com/wMukl.png) and [page 4](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ikmcg.png) from the Oxtoby's book I have mentioned.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, thank you. Can you explain the sentence in the proof "All but a finite number of the intervals $(a_n,b_n)$ would have to precede $I_k$...". I don't really follow the logic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we started discussing this particular proof [in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140648/how-and-why-do-we-prove-that-mathcalli-leq-sum-i-1-infty-mathcall?noredirect=1#comment2328790_1140648), I will copy here the proof from Oxtoby's book Measure and Category. (The second book in the series [Graduate Texts in Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Texts_in_Mathematics).)

> **Theorem 1.5 (Borel).** *If a finite or infinite sequence of intervals $I_n$ covers an interval $I$, then $\sum|I_n|\ge|I|$.
>
> *Proof.* Assume first that $I=[a,b]$ is closed and that all of the intervals $I_n$ are open. 
>   Let $(a_1,b_)$ be the first interval that contains $a$. 
>   If $b_1\le b$, let $(a_2,b_2)$ be the first interval of the sequence that contains $b_1$.
>   If $b_{n-1}\le b$, let $(a_n,b_)$ be the first interval that contains $b_{n-1}$
>   This procedure must terminate with some $b_N>b$. 
>   Otherwise the increasing sequence $\{b_n\}$ would converge to a limit $x\le b$ and $x$ would belong to $I_k$ for some $k$. 
>   All but finite number of intervals would have to precede $I_k$. 
>   This is impossible since no two of these intervals are equal.
>   (Incidental1y, this reasoning reproduces Borel's own proof of the "Heine-Borel theorem" [5, p.228].)
>   We have
>   $$b-a < b_N-a_1 = \sum_{i=2}^N (b_i-b_{i-1}) +b_1-a_1 \le \sum_{i=1}^N (b_i-a_i),$$
>   and so theorem is true in this case.
>
> In the general case, for any $\alpha>1$ let $J$ be a closed subinterval of $I$ with $|J|=|I|/\alpha$, and let $J_n$ be an open interval containing $I_n$ with $|J_n|=\alpha|I_n|$.
>   Then $J$ is covered by the sequence $\{J_n\}$.
>   We have already shown that $\sum|J_n|\ge|J|$.
>   Hence $\alpha\sum|I_n| = \sum|J_n| \ge |J| \ge |I|/\alpha$. Letting $\alpha\to1$ we obtain the desired conclusion.
>
> [5] Borel, E.: Lecons sur la theorie des fonctions. Paris: Gauthier-Villars 1914.

---

The OP asked about this particular step:

> All but finite number of intervals would have to precede $I_k$.

If we have that $b_n\to x$ and $x$ belongs to an open interval $I_k$, then starting from some $n$ each $b_n$ belongs to $I_k$. (From the definition of limit.) But since $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$ was the first interval from the sequence $I_1,I_2,\dots,I_k,\dots$ which contains $b_n$, the interval $I_k$ must come in this sequence at some point *after* the interval $(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})$. This leads to a contradiction, since $I_k$ is preceded only by finitely many intervals (since $k$ is some finite number) and, at the same time, in the proof we constructed infinitely many intervals of the form $(a_n,b_n)$ which precede $I_k$.